# Separting the rows based on elements in the two xolumns present in the timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
data = {'date': ['1998', '2002','1999','2001','1998','2002'], 
        'node1': [1,1,1,1,3,3],
     'node2': [5,3,3,2,4,4],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1,1,1], }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'node1','node2','weight'])
```

Based on two date ranges(98-00 and 01-03) I want to get two separate dataframes(one for each date range) in which only those nodes are present which are present in both the range values.
For eg- in the first row node2:5 is only present in the 98-00 range but not in the 01-03 range so we exclude all the rows with 5(can be in node1 or node2 column).Similarly in second row node1:2 it is only present in 01-02 date range so exclude all rows with value 2 in both the dataframes.)

Expected Output:

in one dataframe:  node1  node2   date

```
               1       3      1999

               3       4       1998
```

2nd dataframe:     node1   node2   date

```
                1       3      2001

                3       4      2002
```

Comment: Essentially this is searching from the two columns node1 and node2 the elements if they are in both the ranges(98-00 and 01-03).If the element is not present in any of the ranges then the rows containing it are not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .between() to filter the desired rows for each dataframe

```
df = df[df.duplicated(['node1','node2'],keep = False)]
df1 = df[df['date'].between('1998', '2000')]
df2 = df[df['date'].between('2001', '2003')]
```

df1

```
    date    node1   node2   weight
2   1999    1       3       1
4   1998    3       4       1
```

df2

```
    date    node1   node2   weight
1   2002    1       3       1
5   2002    3       4       1
```

If the date column is in 1998-02-12 format, convert them to datetime and use .dt accessor to get the year

```
import datetime as dt
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df1 = df[df['date'].dt.year.between(1998, 2000)]
df2 = df[df['date'].dt.year.between(2001, 2003)]
```

Comment: My actual date is in the format 1998-02-12.Will that create problem in this code?as I am getting slightly different answers.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By using `pd.cut`

```
df = df[df.duplicated(['node1','node2'],keep = False)]
df['range']=pd.cut(df.date.astype(int),[1997,2000,2002])

for x,y in df.dropna().groupby('range'):
    print(x)
    print(y)

(1997, 2000]
   date  node1  node2  weight         range
2  1999      1      3       1  (1997, 2000]
4  1998      3      4       1  (1997, 2000]
(2000, 2002]
   date  node1  node2  weight         range
1  2002      1      3       1  (2000, 2002]
5  2002      3      4       1  (2000, 2002]
```

You can store them in a list

```
l=[]

for _,y in df.dropna().groupby('range'):
    l.append(y)
```